# sendmail rbl.m4 missing on centos

Tags: sendmail, centos7

So I'm getting this error when trying to m4 sendmail.mc:

`` cannot open `/usr/share/sendmail-cf/feature/rbl.m4': No such file or directory ``

as it is obviously not there. I have done `yum install sendmail-cf` but it still doesn't have the file. I'm working on CentOS 7.0.1406.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FEATURE(rbl) was removed in sendmail-8.12.0 (see quote from  [RELEASE_NOTES](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/older_release_notes/) below).
Use  [FEATURE(dnsbl)](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/features.html#dnsbl) or [FEATURE(enhdnsbl)](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/features.html#enhdnsbl) instead.

Carefully inspect [DNSBL](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) list you use. It **requires** very careful maintenance at least every few years.

---

Sendmail's [RELEASE_NOTES](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/older_release_notes/) file:

```
8.12.0/8.12.0 2001/09/08
  [...]
  CONFIG: Removed deprecated FEATURE(`rbl').
  [...]
  Deleted Files:
     cf/feature/rbl.m4
```